# jquery function to call WCF REST service

Tags: jquery, jsonp

What would be the correct function to call the following WCF REST service

```
http://xx.x.x.xxx/GAdmin/WGService/Service1.svc/RetrieveData?term=apple
```

with the following parameters added

```
term=apple
username:joe password:pote
```

and being json it should be have a callback function for jsonp

```
  $.getJSON('http://xx.x.x.xxx/GAdmin/WGService/Service1.svc/RetrieveData?term=apple
  callback=?'{
 content: { username: "joe", password: "pote" },
 function (data)
 {
    alert('Received ' + data + ' results');
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Cannot figure out problem but if possible go throught this post

[Steps to Call WCF Service using jQuery](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2010/12/steps-to-call-wcf-service-using-jquery.html)

[Create REST service with WCF and Consume using jQuery](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2011/03/rest.html)

[Calling Cross Domain WCF service using Jquery/Javascript](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2011/06/calling-cross-domain-wcf-service-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you're WCF service is currently configured, but the following code block will call the service and the results would be passed into the callback.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "http://xx.x.x.xxx/GAdmin/WGService/Service1.svc/RetrieveData?term=apple",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {
        /* SUCCESS FUNCTION */
    },
    error: function (error) {
        /* ERROR FUNCTION */
    }
});
```